# error: Cannot find form control with name: CreatedOn in Angular

Tags: angular

When I set the response value to FormGroup varriable (programTypeForm) using  this.programTypeForm.setValue(programType) then I got the error
"Cannot find form control with name: CreatedOn." in Subscriber.js file

```js
this.programTypeForm = this.fb.group({
            VersionNumber:[null],
            ProgramTypeID: [null],
            ProgramTypeName: [null, Validators.required],
            ProgramTypeEnglishName: [null, Validators.required],
            OrganizationID: [null],
            OrganizationHierarchyID: [null],
            LanguageID: ["Asdf"],
            UserID: [11],
            CurrencyID:["Asdasd"]
        });
```

```js
 if(this.programTypeId>0)
       {
        //  alert(this.programTypeId);
         this._userService.get("ProgramType/getProgramTypeDetailById/" + this.programTypeId)
         .subscribe(programType => {
            alert(programType.VersionNumber);
            this.programTypeForm.setValue(programType); 
            console.log(programType);
          
         },
         error => this.msg = <any>error);
       }
```

Comment: i guess the service call is returning a key value of key CreatedOn, can you check that

Comment: show object returned from service

Comment: But I don't want to use that field or key CreatedOn in angular side then what  should I need to do

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, your incoming response seems to have  property `CreatedOn`, which is not included in your form, thus the error. If you want to only pick specific properties from your response, you can do that by modifying your `setValue()` to something like this:

```ts
this.programTypeForm.setValue({
  VersionNumber: programType.VersionNumber, // here assuming the propertynames match...
  ProgramTypeID: programType.ProgramTypeID,
  // ... rest omitted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patchValue` not `setValue`. like this:

```
this.programTypeForm.patchValue(programType);
```